# Can't get value from CharField in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

It is not possible to get the value of the username field in the `User` class.

If output through print - everything is correct, but if passed as a parameter, it gives `django.db.models.fields.CharField`. 
Through `str` and `__str__` it passes the same thing.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance, usrname=instance.username)
```

I use the parameter as follows -

```
usrname = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
upload = 'img/users/%s' % usrname
img = models.FileField(upload_to=upload, blank=True)
```

Tell me, please, what I'm doing wrong.

Code from models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usrname = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    upload = 'img/users/%s' % usrname
    img = models.FileField(upload_to=upload, blank=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance, usrname=instance.username)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I'm using the standard `User` model from library `django.contrib.auth`, not custom.

Comment: Firstly, I highly recommend it using the User model from library django.contrib.auth. It will help you. For any reason you decide that this model isn't fit your solution please provide us with the detailed `models.py` file.

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos updated the question

Comment: Is `instance.username` holds some value? or is that `empty/null` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but you certainly can't do what you're trying to do in the upload_to parameter. This is a class-level definition and doesn't have access to the instance, let alone the value of the field on any instance.

As [the docs show](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), the way to set the upload dynamically is to use a callable function.

```
def upload_username(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('img/users', instance.username, filename)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usrname = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    img = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_username, blank=True)
```

Note though that there doesn't seem to be any good reason to set the username separately on the Profile model. The username is always available via the User model, so what's the point in storing it on the profile as well?

Comment: Oh, that's what I need. Apparently, I do not carefully read the documentation.
Thanks for the answer!